# Getting rid of Aero theme on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, aero

I have Windows Vista on my computer and whenever I login, I always have that aero theme. It's usually see-through/clear, but now it's not. How I can fix this?

Comment: You want it see-through again or you DON'T want it?

Comment: Aero **is** the transparent (see-through/clear) Windows and all the special effects.

Comment: The title says: Getting rid of Aero, while his question says: How can I fix it? Contradictionary aint it? It should be: How to I restore the Aero theme?

Comment: If it's just the theme you don't like, look into custom themes - getting rid of something as useful as the dwm is a silly idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change Aero settings, right click on your desktop and choose "Customise"

You should then be able to choose "Window Color and Appearance" to change transparency and other options.

[image]

You can also click the text at the bottom "Open classic appearance properties for more color options." which should allow you to turn Aero off/on (Sorry, it is not very clear from your question what you are trying to do, so trying to show both solutions!)

[image]

Comment: Or take a look at this How-To-Geek article, which elaborates on it! You beat me to it Wil ;-)

Comment: what article, Ivo?